# My code is not formatting correctly in wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have made a code where when the timer starts, and it reaches to "5" minutes first then the color starts to change and then when it hits to "10" minutes then the color changes again and so on.

But when I used my code inside the WordPress the color starts changing underneath the footer instead of the actual page itself.

```js
let seconds = 0;
let minutes = 0;
let hours = 0;

let displaySeconds = 0;
let displayMinutes = 0;
let displayHours = 0;

let interval = null;

let status = "stopped";

//Stopwatch function
function stopWatch(){

    seconds++;
    if(seconds / 60 === 1){
        seconds = 0;
        minutes++;

        if(minutes / 60 === 1){
            minutes = 0;
            hours++;
        }
    }

    if(seconds < 10){
        displaySeconds = "0" + seconds.toString();
    }
    else{
        displaySeconds = seconds;
    }

    if(minutes < 10){
        displayMinutes = "0" + minutes.toString();
    }
    else{
        displayMinutes = minutes;
    }
    if(hours < 10){
        displayHours = "0" + hours.toString();
    }
    else{
        displayHours = hours;
    }

    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = displayHours + ":" + displayMinutes + ":" + displaySeconds;

    changeColor();
}


function startStop(){
    if(status === "stopped"){
        interval = window.setInterval(stopWatch, 1000);
        document.getElementById("startStop").innerHTML = "Stop";
        status = "started";
    }
    else{
        window.clearInterval(interval);
        document.getElementById("startStop").innerHTML = "Start";
        status = "stopped";
    }
}

//Function to reset stopwatch
function reset(){
    window.clearInterval(interval);
    counter = 0;
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "00:00:00";
    document.getElementById("startStop").innerHTML = "Start";

}

function changeColor(){

    var tSeconds = seconds + (minutes * 60) + (hours * 60 * 60)

    if (tSeconds === 300){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
    else if (tSeconds === 600){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    }
    else if (tSeconds === 900){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}

reset();
startStop();
```

```css
.container{
    height: 300px;
    width: 100;
}

#display{
    font-size:72px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

.buttons{
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Daily Scrum</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Timestyle.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="Timescript.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="containter">

        <div id="display">
            00:00:00
        </div>

        <div class="buttons">
            <button id="startStop" onclick="startStop()">Start</button> <button id="reset"onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
        </div>

    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

If you have any solutions please let me know.

Comment: It looks like it is working fine here, you problem is not related to this piece of code.

Comment: *color starts changing underneath the footer instead of the actual page itself* That should be because the background of your WordPress page is not the background of the body `document.body.style.backgroundColor`. You should inspect how is build the website and changes the `backgroundColor` of the right DOM Element.

Comment: @robinvrd Thank you, I will see

Comment: @robinvrd It does work fine in general, but when you put the code within the WordPress, it does not work properly.

Comment: @robinvrd Is there something I can change within the code that will target the specific area of the page within WordPress? So far I tried to change the width of the container etc... but nothing changed it always changing color underneath the footer.

Comment: You just need to figure which element you want to change the background color of because you are currently targetting the body `document.body`. After you've find the element it should have a `id` or `class` attribute. Then you will be able to target your element and change its background with : `document.getElementId("...").style.backgroundColor` or `document.getElementsByClassName("...")[0].style.backgroundColor`

Comment: @robinvrd I tried your solutions, unfortunately, it did not work. This time no color changed after a certain time.

Comment: Is your wordpress up out there for me to test it and see what you should do ?

Comment: @robinvrd Yes it is here it is... http://ebeessolutions.com/daily-scrum-timer

Comment: Looks like your page is wrapped in `<div id="content"></div>`, try with `document.getElementId("content").style.backgroundColor` instead of `document.body.style.backgroundColor`.

Comment: @robinvrd I used your method but unfortunately, nothing changed.

Comment: Just to be sure try to add ` !important` after the color like this `document.getElementId("content").style.backgroundColor = "red !important"`.

Comment: @robinvrd You can check again, nothing changes with the "!important".